# How to rename files with the name of their parent directory?

Tags: bash, shell, file-management

I'd like to rename the `recon.text` file with its directory name. I have 1000 directories. Some help, please?

```
7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha/recon.text
8_S1_R1_001_tri15_sha/recon.text
9_S8_R1_001_tri20_sha/recon.text
10_S5_R1_001_tri25_sha/recon.text
11_S3_R1_001_tri30_sha/recon.text
```

Comment: Your files are named `recon.text`, not `recon.txt`. See you mistyped my answer, `for file in */recon.text`.

Comment: HI it worked, but I'd like to add a suffix .dab to the rename file. How should I do ?

Comment: @sunnykevin Just change the mv second argument to `"${file%/*}/${file%/*}.dab"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [rename](/questions/tagged/rename):

```
rename -n 's!(.*sha)/recon\.text!$1/$1.txt!' */recon.text
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good to rename for real.

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

For RedHat-family distros:

```
yum install prename
```

The 'prename' package is in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

---

For archlinux:

```
pacman -S perl-rename
```

---

For *BSD:

```
pkg install gprename
```

or `p5-File-Rename`

---

For Mac users:

```
brew install rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: I tried rename, it doesn't work out for me.Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Just fixed a typo, should works if `file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"` return something with `Perl` like I explained in my answer

Answer (score 3):

Using only standard tools, you can execute this in the parent directory:

```
for file in */recon.text; do mv -- "$file" "${file%/*}/${file%/*}"; done
```

It renames each found `$file` to `${file%/*}/${file%/*}`, where `${file%/*}` means "the file path with `/[anything...]` removed.

For example, for `7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha/recon.text` file,

- `${file%/*}` expands to `7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha`
- Then `${file%/*}/${file%/*}` is `7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha/7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha`.
- Then the operation performed is `mv -- "7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha/recon.text" "7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha/7_S4_R1_001_tri10_sha"`.

You can add an echo between `do` and `mv` to see what the command would do before actually executing it.

Comment: `rename` is also standard, but there's mainly 2 versions: perl or util-linux. But all distros have 'rename'  AFAIK

Comment: @GillesQuenot `rename` is not part of the POSIX specification. I tried your solution, but it didn't work with the `rename` I have in my machine, probably I don't have the correct `rename` for the job, as you explained.

Comment: Are _parameter expansions_ POSIX ? I doubt

Comment: They are, you can find them in the [Shell Command Language](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) part of the specification.

Comment: You maybe should mention that OP need to remove `echo` or you are assuming everyone will understand. I doubt too :)

Comment: Quasimodo answer doesn't worked out.